# Android json parsing isn't yielding expected results

Tags: android, mysql, json, parsing, textview

I've read and tried a lot of examples on stackoverflow before asking but so far no luck. What I'm trying to do is parse a json array that I'm getting back from php/mysql for use in Android. My code works up to the point that I can convert the json into a string which looks like this after the conversion:

```
[{"username":"lawn edge","distance":"0.00766418723166294"},{"username":"bbq","distance":"0.00876051437108357"},{"username":"Tablet","distance":"0.0140815866739065"}]
```

I'm trying to extract just the "username" and send them to a textview. Most examples I've tried just produce an empty textview or it's dumping the entire json string as it looks above. The closest I've gotten is using the code below:

```
private void returnJson() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try {

        httpPostproximity = new HttpPost(
                "http://vtolblog.com/finddistance.php");
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat", lat));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lng", lng));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", check));
        httpPostproximity
                .setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPostproximity);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        playerlist.setText("error3");
    }

    try {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\r\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();
        result.trim();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        playerlist.setText("error2");
    }
    try {
        JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray jArreglo = new JSONArray(result);
        for (int i = 0; i < jArreglo.length(); i++) {
            json_data = jArreglo.getJSONObject(i);
            Log.i("log_tag", "Player: " + json_data.getString("username"));
            // Get an output to the screen
            jsonplayers += "\n\t" + jArreglo.getJSONObject(i);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        playerlist.setText("Error parsing json");
    }

    playerlist.setText(jsonplayers);

    return;

    // end of returnJson()
}
```

If I change playerlist.setText(result); it will display the above referenced json array so I'm assuming the code is okay until that point? 
Am I way off? If you need anything else to help me please let me know and thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting exception on line:

```
JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
```

because result is JSONArray, not JSONObject, try commenting this line.

Comment: When I comment that out I end up with a blank textview. Maybe the whole problem I'm having is I keep trying to apply code that is looking for json objects and not treating it like an array?